Spatie Laravel media library with Spatie image v3 need help updating code
I am running Laravel 11 with filamentphp 3.2.100, filament/spatie-laravel-media-library-plugin": "^3.2", "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^11".
Before updating Laravel 10 to laravel 11 and updating PHP version and all compose packages and dependencis the fallowing code from in my model would work correctly.  With the update i had to update some spatie packages including upgrading to Spatie Image v3 that deprecates the old Manipulations file and is replaced by a new one.
Old code:
public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
{
$this->addMediaConversion('867_867')
                ->format(Manipulations::FORMAT_WEBP)
                ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 867, 867)
                ->optimize()
                ->performOnCollections('AnuncioUno');

            $this->addMediaConversion('425_425')
                ->format(Manipulations::FORMAT_WEBP)
                ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 425, 425)
                ->optimize()
                ->performOnCollections('AnuncioUno');
}

With the new Spatie image v3 file i am not sure how to perform the same action.  What i did to make it work was copy the old Manipulations file to App\Spatie\Image\Hack\Manipulations and import the old class:
New code:
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;
// Hack
use App\Spatie\Image\Hack\Manipulations;
use Spatie\Image\Enums\Fit;
use Spatie\Image\Image;

public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
        {
            $this->addMediaConversion('867_867')
                ->format(Manipulations::FORMAT_WEBP)
                ->fit(Fit::Crop, 867, 867)
                ->optimize()
                ->performOnCollections('AnuncioUno');

            $this->addMediaConversion('425_425')
                ->format(Manipulations::FORMAT_WEBP)
                ->fit(Fit::Crop, 425, 425)
                ->optimize()
                ->performOnCollections('AnuncioUno');


This hack works, but im using the old Manipulations file and the new Fit enum.  I would like to convert the img from any format to webp using the current v3 standard but im not sure how to go about doing that.   Any one have any tips?
Convert image from any img format to webp and reduce the file size.
